# How come you can put a question mark in file names?

Tags: filesystem

In Windows, you can't put a `?` in a file or directory name, because they are reserved characters for PHP GET functions and wildcards. But in Ubuntu, I can. I can name a file `lol?.txt` and access it properly like any other file. How come you can do this safely in Ubuntu, when you can't in Windows?

Comment: Windows is NOT a standard and has never been, they have invented some very obscure things over the lifetime - that has been considered a 'de facto standard'. See this http://www.linux.com/community/blogs/133-general-linux/760530-linux-shell-tip-remove-files-with-names-that-contains-spaces-and-special-characters-such-as- for some insight. Another place to look is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10003416/3720510) - I hope you realize from these that you're in a marshland. I suggest you keep filenames pure ASCII (i.e. single byte chars, not UTF, restrict to A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and maybe some more)

Comment: More: [Google](https://www.google.se/?gfe_rd=cr&safe=off#q=linux+filenames+with+special+characters&safe=off)

Comment: For what it is worth: "Standard" (not a 'de facto') is something that has been negotiated and agreed upon by either a national standards committee, or ISO. IETF may be seen as a 'national comittee' in this regard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reasoning behind the first statement is false. That is a restriction from the DOS era, well before PHP or even HTTP was born. See [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_filename):

> The long filename system allows a maximum length of 255 UCS-2 characters <sup>[3](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810456.aspx) [4](http://home.teleport.com/~brainy/lfn.htm)</sup> including spaces and non-alphanumeric characters (excluding the following characters, which have special meaning within the COMMAND.COM command interpreter or the operating system kernel: `\ / : * ? " < > |`).

Thus it is more of a DOS restriction than a Linux/Unix permissiveness.

Comment: Wait, so if I understand you correctly, the restriction of not being able to use these characters in windows has absolutely no purpose? At all?

Comment: @latias1290 It does: Backward Compatibility. And never underestimate the power of Backward Compatibility.

Comment: @latias1290 the windows kernel allows for special chars AND also supports case sensetivity (it is the windows software itself that imposes these limits)

Comment: @Rinzwind indeed. The (now defunct?) Subsystem for Unix Applications was POSIX compliant and not as restrictive.